# Maximum length of document size/Character we can provide to get sentiment, named entity recognition, NLP services GCP,IBM,Amazon comprehand?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, ibm-cloud

I want to use Natural language processing service to get sentiment analysis, topic modelling, named entity recognition in my conversational data. I want to know what is the maximum size of data/maximum character that I can provide in order to get all NLP service. Maximum characters set that I can give?

I want a definitive reply with exact txt file size or maximum character that I can provide.